# JQuery hide() not working after show() and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

Variations of this question have been asked but it appears that most were solved using the `toggle()` method.  My scenario is different in that the `hide()` and `show()` should be driven by two different events, the creation of a new game and when the game is won.  I don't want each event to do only one thing, so `toggle()` would not be appropriate.

I'm using socket.io to communicate between the server and browser.  Everything loads appropriately to begin.  The issue is with trying to start a new game after the previous game has been won.  The relevant JavaScript looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   socket.on('gameOver', function() {
      $('.yourStatus').hide(700);
      $('.winner').show(700);
   });
   $('button.newGame').on('click', function() {
      $('.winner').hide;
      $('.yourStatus').show;
   });
});
```

Everything works as it should when the game ends via the socket.io event.  Everything else within the button click event function works properly except for `hide()` and `show()`.

I'm sure the answer to this will be embarrassingly simple.

Comment: `$('.winner').hide`  does not call the function `hide` because you forgot the `()`. It should be `$('.winner').hide()` and the same is for `show`

Comment: We all need to ask questions where the answers are embarrassing simple at times! :)

Answer (score 1):

you should use brackets (invoke the function):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   socket.on('gameOver', function() {
      $('.yourStatus').hide(700);
      $('.winner').show(700);
   });
   $('button.newGame').on('click', function() {
      $('.winner').hide();
      $('.yourStatus').show();
   });
});
```

**Performance tip** (of cource if it is possible - element could be unique in DOM):

better if you declare your '.winner' with hash. For example: `<div id="winner"/>` and use in separator jQuery: `$("#winner")`

Comment: There won't be a noticeable performance benefit for events that are fired at such a low rate like `click`  or `gameOver` (and for high frequent events it would be better to cache the result of the selector anyway). But if an element is unique it indeed might be a good idea to use unique identifier.

Comment: @t.niese yes, I had add in brackets: "of course if it's possible" - it means that if element is unique in DOM. Thanks you for advice. I'm going to change the description

Comment: Sorry that was a misunderstanding, I believe that it is possible to use ids there because `yourStatus` and `winner` sound quiet unique. The comment was more bout the `Perrformance tip` because this sounds like using a _class selector_ in callback of a low frequent event has a noticeable worser performance then the _id selector_.

Comment: I knew it would be embarrassing and it managed to be several times more embarrassing than I expected.  It works now - thanks.

Comment: Btw it's not a performance tip, it's actually a complete change in behaviour. Using the class selector means all Dom elements with that class. You are assuming that the class is only being used once. This may not be the case.

Comment: @RhysBradbury I think your answer was not thought out. I wrote - if it is possible. Complaining is not the way to improve other